# rails 4: ancestry doesn't work properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

I have a problem when try to do root_id of one object. Class looks like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  ancestry   :string(255)

class PackageCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_ancestry
end
```

that database table looks:

```
id   name         ancestry
1    Root         NULL
2    Child 1-1    1
3    Child 1-2    1
4    Child 2-1    2
5    Child 3-1    4
```

When I do:

```
@p = PackageCategory.find 5
puts @p.root_id
```

I am getting: `4`

When I type:

```
@p.path_ids
```

I am getting: `[4, 5]`

`puts @p.name` gives me `Child 3-1` (and it's correct)

So, where is a problem? Shouldn't I get in the first case `1` and in the second `[1, 2, 4, 5]` ?

Comment: Please, let me know your convention of names: Child 3-1 means first child of id 3?

Comment: no, there is no convention of names, I took them without any order. That "Child 3-1" name has id 5 (as it shown in the table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, I can say that `ancestry` column is not well formated. Because, if I look the record with id 4 (Child 2-1) its ancestry says his parent is the record id 2, and the record 2 is a root record. And that is false.

The format at ancestry column is 'root_id/son_id/son_id/.../parent_of_current_record_id'.

The ancestry column of record id 4 must be set with:

```
pc = PackageCategory.find(4)
pc.parent = PackageCategory.find(2)
pc.save
```

or

```
pc.parent_id = 2
pc.save
```

And the ancestry gem build the ancestry column.